# Passing a parameter to the Subreport and Displayin it only if Parameter is passed in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport

I am trying to work on a report which has yearly records of employees. I have a created a table and a chart based on this.
Now I want to create a subreport which would display monthly records for the YEAR in the main report.
The report runs perfect when I drillthrough, but have to use subreport in order to achieve this.
So basically The main report has

## Parameter: Employee

The second report has:

## Parameter: Employee and Year

The SubReport should not show up if Year on the Main table is not clicked.
Can you please tell me how this is done.

Update:

I tried creating the subreport , but the it takes the top most year and displays the subreport and when I click on other "Years" it gives me an error.(Takes me to another page)

Answer (score 0):

There are subreports which are embedded in the report itself and then there are linked reports. In this situation it sounds like a linked report would work better. In the properties of your year values go to Action. Select "Go to report". Enter the path of the report and then the parameters you want to pass. So you could pass the employee ID and the Year.

[image]

On the linked report, there should be a built-in button to go back to the main report or you can just add a link to go back one page. This is how I've implemented drill-down/subreports for our solutions.

Comment: The above solution works but When on second page and they try change the Employee name, The report does not change or comes back to the first page....

Comment: They would either need to go back to the original report and click on a different name or use the parameter selection at the top and click "View Report" to refresh it.